# MySQL: Joining currency codes

Tags: mysql, join, left-join, currency

I am still a MySQL novice but I am trying to join the latest fx rates to a list of currencies where the currency code is the primary key.

The join returns nulls when trying to join on the currency code but does not when joined to other tables that contain the same currency code. Reduced example below.

fx_rates table

```
date,        close_price, currency
2017-06-21,  1.6772,      AUD
2017-06-21,  1.6881,      CAD
2017-06-21,  1.2329,      CHF
2017-06-21,  1.1356,      EUR
```

currency table

```
currency, cur_name
AUD,      AUSTRALIAN DOLLAR
CAD,      CANADIAN DOLLAR
CHF,      SWISS FRANC
EUR,      EURO
```

Currency is the primary key of the currency table and a foreign key in the fx_rates table. However, when i try and run the below query:

**

```
select  cur_name, c.currency, fx.close_price
from currency c left join fx_rates fx on fx.currency = c.currency
```

**

I get

```
cur_name,          currency, close_price
AUSTRALIAN DOLLAR, AUD ,     NULL
CANADIAN DOLLAR,   CAD ,     NULL
SWISS FRANC,       CHF ,     NULL
EURO ,             EUR ,     NULL
```

Massive thank you if you can resolve this.

schema

```html
-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `atl`.`Currency`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `atl`.`Currency` (
  `currency` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `cur_name` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `bbg_ticker` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `pair_name` TEXT(100) NULL,
  `long_pair_name` TEXT(100) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`currency`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;



-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `atl`.`FX_Rates`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `atl`.`FX_Rates` (
  `Date` DATE NOT NULL,
  `close_price` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `currency` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  INDEX `currency_idx` (`currency` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `currency`
    FOREIGN KEY (`currency`)
    REFERENCES `atl`.`Currency` (`currency`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Comment: Looks like everything okay in your query. Problem can be in spaces, for example `AUD` in one of tables can be 'AUD ', then 'AUD'!='AUD ', do you use ENUM datatype for this column? Maybe you can provide more info related schema structure?

Comment: That's why it's better to use auto-increment integer rather than varchar as primary key.

Comment: @alexeypalamar Hi, thanks for having a look. No i do not use ENUM. WIll that resolve the problem?

Comment: Please don't use this schema, it's very bad configuration for perfomance. currency column should be at least enum type, or maybe you can use integer primary key instead of `AUD`,`CAD`, e.t.c? https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/enum.html

Comment: @alexeypalamar Thanks, Alexey. I will read into this and make the change.